# UriPathExtensionMapping in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How do I use UriPathExtensionMapping in MVC4?  I've added the mapping in the formatter such that:

```
MediaTypeMappings.Add(new UriPathExtensionMapping("json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"))
```

But I can't use the extension on my route unless I add a verb, such as:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{extension}"

        );
```

Then it'll recognize my desired media type, but it also starts expecting "extension" as a parameter on the action.  Example:

```
    public object Get(string extension)
    {
    }
```

Instead of just:

```
    public object Get()
    {
    }
```

How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember if I noticed this problem, but it might be because I explicitly specified the default value for the extension like:

```
var rF = routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi.v1.format",
    routeTemplate: "api/1/{controller}/{action}.{format}/{*id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, format = "json", version = 1 }
);
```

*note `format = "json"` in the line beginning with `defaults`.

I did also notice that this sometimes doesn't work on requests with trailing parameters for `id`, like `~/api/1/values/get.json/4`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro this problem.

You are right that, to use UriPathExtensionMapping, you will need to specify the {controller}.{ext} in your route, like what you described above. If you only specify the {controller}, and uri looks like ~/home.json, then the controller token will be mapped to home.json, which is probably not what you wanted.

However, you should not need to require an "extension" parameter in your action. If you continue seeing this problem, can you post your entire repro, including your controller, your routes and configuration set up with custom formatter? thank you.

Comment: The extension is to use with WebApi, it's to specify whether data is returned as XML or json, irrespective of Conneg.  The extension should not match the controller... that is just silly.  Using a QueryStringMapping allows me to do things like "format=json" without effecting my route, why can't I append ".<format>" to the end of a URL without it effecting my route?

Comment: Also that was a simplified route adding something like "api/{controller}.{extension}/{id}" or "/api/{controller}/{id}.{extension}" does not form a matches well, especially if {id} is optional.  UriPathExtensionMapping should not have effect on the route.  It just break things.  The route does not use my {extension} but without it specified somewhere in the route matching, nothing will be processed for conneg to be overridden.