# UriPathExtensionMapping in WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Weird stuff is going on when I try to add extension mapping features to my api. Some things work but I cant get anything to properly return JSON. These related questions haven't gotten me where I need to go:

- [UriPathExtensionMapping to control response format in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728152/uripathextensionmapping-to-control-response-format-in-webapi)
- [UriPathExtensionMapping in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520842/uripathextensionmapping-in-mvc-4)

My project has both HttpRoutes and HttpAttributeRoutes enabled. Not sure if that matters - I am just using the default WebApi project template. I've got the following routes:

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Api UriPathExtension",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}",
    defaults: new { }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Api UriPathExtension ID 1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}.{ext}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "Api UriPathExtension ID 2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}.{ext}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here's my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/roundTypes")]
public class RoundTypesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/roundTypes
    [Route("")][HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Vcijis.RoundType> GetAllRoundTypes()
```

When I test it:

```
http://localhost/api/roundTypes **works** but is XML
http://localhost/api/roundTypes/ **works**  (also XML)
http://localhost/api/roundTypes.json returns **404**
http://localhost/api/roundTypes.json/ returns a **JSON formatted error**
```

The JSON error message I get is:

```
{"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 
'http://localhost/api/roundTypes.json/'.",
"messageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'RoundTypes' 
that matches the request."}
```

I've also tried with an **id** parameter and get similar results. I can't seem to get {ext} working in HttpAttributeRoutes at all. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributed controllers/actions cannot be reached from routes matched to conventional ones. So you would need to use attribute routing to specify the `{ext}` in your route templates.

One example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/customers")]
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/customers.{ext}")]
    [Route]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Get All Customers";
    }

    [Route("{id}.{ext}")]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "Get Single Customer";
    }

    [Route]
    public string Post(Customer customer)
    {
        return "Created Customer";
    }

    [Route("{id}")]
    public string Put(int id, Customer customer)
    {
        return "Updated Customer";
    }

    [Route("{id}")]
    public string Delete(int id)
    {
        return "Deleted Customer";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiran - I am so close! Your solution works for `.json/` with a trailing slash but not `.json` without. Also, I tried removing the RouteAttribute all together (which I prefer--I don't want to constantly specify `{ext}`). However, I get the same result. I even added one more `config.Routes` (in OP) and I get the same result...

Comment: Are you sure...I am unable to repro the issue you are mentioning. Also as I mentioned in my post, any controller/actions which are decorated with attribute routes (ex: in your case `GetAllRoundTypes`) cannot be reached by the conventional routes (i.e the routes added via `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` extension)...

Comment: Yes, I get a 404. When I removed the attributes I renamed the controller method to `Get()`. Maybe there is something I need to look at with my IISExpress config...

Comment: Adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` to `<system.webServer>` did the trick, as suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345810/routing-of-file-like-names-in-asp-net-webapi). I'm not sure if this is the best approach though? It seems like this may kill static file output caching?

Anyway, that's probably a discussion for a separate question. Accepting your answer!